# redirect including query string with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect a page like this (values could change in query string)

http://www.domain.com/list.php?id=bla&variable2=product1-product2-product3

Redirect to

http://www.domain.com/list.html?id=bla&variable2=product1-product2-product3

All i need is it to change to .html but everything else should remain the same on the bespoke links.

Any help out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a bad idea to do the redirection in list.php file instead of using an .htaccess file?

How about something like:

```
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/list.html?'+$querystring);
```

in `list.php`?

Comment: But the trouble is i need to get the page to display outside all the framework rules and redirect...thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in you htaccess, it should be enough.

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+).html$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

(And by the way, it's useless to do this...)